# How to override save method of model to change filefield name?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a ModelForm in my django app which allows a user to upload a file and store it to aws storage s3. What I wish to do is rename the file from its original name to the name of the field `timestamp`. What I have tried so far is overriding the save method of the model. Here is my code:

models.py

```
 from converter.storage_backends import CsvStorage
 from django.db import models
 from django.utils import timezone
 import time



 class CSVUpload(models.Model):
   csv_file = models.FileField(storage=CsvStorage())
   timestamp = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default= time.time())

   def __str__(self):
      return self.csv_file


   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.csv_file.name = self.timestamp + ".csv"
    super(CSVUpload, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
  from django import forms
  from .models import CSVUpload
  import time

  class CsvForm(forms.ModelForm):

  csv_file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(
      attrs= {
        'class': 'form-group',
      }
   ))

  timestamp = forms.CharField(initial = time.time())

  class Meta:
    model = CSVUpload
    fields = ('csv_file', 'timestamp',)

  def save(self):
    csvfile = super(CsvForm, self).save()
    return csvfile
```

my view:

```
 def uploadcsv(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = CsvForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
        return redirect(about)
   else:
    form = CsvForm()
    return render(request, 'myapp/uploadcsv.html',{'form': form})
```

**EDIT**

storage_backends.py

```
  from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage 
  from django.conf import settings

  class CsvStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
     location = settings.AWS_CSV_LOCATION    
     file_overwrite = False
```

Despite that, when I upload the file it doesnt arrive on the bucket. I am not sure what is wrong but I suspect it lies on the save method. Could someone help me understand how to resolve this? I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Django has a built-in parameter for `FileField`, which accepts a function where you specify the filename of your object. The parameter is called `upload_to`, you can find details from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

Answer (score 0):

Django's [**`FileField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) has support for specifying the upload filename with the [**`upload_to`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

> (..)
>
> `upload_to` may also be a callable, such as a function. This will be
>   called to obtain the upload path, including the filename. This
>   callable must accept two arguments and return a Unix-style path (with
>   forward slashes) to be passed along to the storage system. (..)

So we can implement this with:

```
class CSVUpload(models.Model):

    def get_csv_name(self, filename):
        return '{}.csv'.format(self.timestamp)

    csv_file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_csv_name, storage=CsvStorage())
    timestamp = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default= time.time())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.csv_file
```

Comment: Hey thanks for you answer! This doesnt upload the file to the s3 bucket with the timestamp name, in fact it still doesnt upload it there at all

Comment: @alordlord: what is your `CsvStorage` here?

Comment: @alord: you will need to use an s3storage, if you want to upload this to the s3 bucket: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html and here on hwo to specify a bucket: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

Comment: Hey I have updated my question! Uploading to the bucket works until I try to rename the file. After this the file is not being uploaded anymore

Comment: @alordlord: by you should not rename the file. As far as I know, the storage can not handle renamings, since it is not part of the `Storage` interface (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.save). That's why you thus need to use `upload_to` to privde a name directly.